# windows 7 batch script- if statement not working

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file

```
cd C:\Users\user1\Desktop

if "%time:~0,1%" == " "
ren 85.txt %time:~1,1%.txt 
else ren 85.txt %time:~o,1%.txt 

pause
```

The script above is not working, but if I put the following line into file:

```
ren 85.txt %time:~1,1%.txt
```

it is working.

Why is the `if...else` statement above not working?

Answer (score 3):

```
cd C:\Users\user1\Desktop

if "%time:~0,1%" == " " (
 ren 85.txt %time:~1,1%.txt 
) else (
   ren 85.txt %time:~0,1%.txt 
)

pause
```

You need a brackets , or one line if statement : `if "%time:~0,1%" == " "  ren 85.txt %time:~1,1%.txt`

Answer (score 3):

`o`  doesn't work, try it with `0` (zero):

```
cd C:\Users\user1\Desktop

if "%time:~0,1%"==" " (ren 85.txt %time:~1,1%.txt 
) else ren 85.txt %time:~0,1%.txt 

pause
```